# CS1061 error during deployment/Codebehind not working

Tags: c#, deployment

I'm fairly new to asp.net, and I'm using Visual Studio 08 to make a small (1-page) Web app.

It works flawlessly when I test it using the debugging thing, but when I try to put it on my webspace I get:

CS1061: Type `ASP.test_default_aspx' does not contain a definition for`name_TextChanged' and no extension method `name_TextChanged' of type`ASP.test_default_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Description: HTTP 500. Error processing request.

This happens if I make anything that has a codebehind on it. I tried testing with a page that didn't and it worked just fine.

I tried rebuilding before uploading it, deleting designer.cs, and reuploading the library and I'm not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

When you copy the code files to your web space, do you delete the existing files in your web space before copying. Obosloete files that you removed from your solution won't get automatically removed from your web space.

Also, consider pre-compiling your website before deploying to the your web server. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227972.aspx

Comment: Well, I deleted the files this time when I uploaded them instead of overwriting them, and it threw me the same error.

Also, it's a web application and that site says that I can't really precompile a web application.